# Struts2 warning : Could not find property

Tags: hibernate, struts2, warnings

I have a project which I am using Hibernate and Struts2, and I am new to both of them.

it works fine but i still have those warning

```
mai 19, 2014 4:56:57 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack warn
WARNING: Could not find property [templateDir]
mai 19, 2014 4:56:58 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack warn
WARNING: Could not find property [struts.actionMapping]
```

Any advice on how to eliminate the warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the old [Troubleshooting guide migrating from Struts 2.0 to 2.1](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/S2WIKI/Troubleshooting+guide+migrating+from+Struts+2.0.x+to+2.1.x):

> ### Reduce verbose logging
>
> Struts 2.1 introduces more verbose logging than Struts 2.0. While
>   extremely valuable, some users may find these annoying.
>
> #### Missing Properties
>
> This message states that the framework searched for a property in the
>   value stack and failed to find it.
>
> ```
> 2008-04-19 14:21:08,177 WARN  [http-8443-Processor25] [OgnlValueStack] Could not find property [templateDir]
> 2008-04-19 14:21:08,177 WARN  [http-8443-Processor25] [OgnlValueStack] Could not find property [templateDir]
> 2008-04-19 14:21:08,177 WARN  [http-8443-Processor25] [OgnlValueStack] Could not find property [templateDir]
> 2008-04-19 14:21:08,178 WARN  [http-8443-Processor25] [OgnlValueStack] Could not find property [org.apache.catalina.jsp_file]
> ```
>
> To hide these messages, turn off the WARN level logging for
>   OgnlValueStack.
>
> eg. Include a new limit category in your **log4j.xml** file (only log
>   errors or worse):
>
> ```
> <category name="com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack">
>     <priority value="error"/>
> </category>
> ```

Comment: Where can i find log4j.xml file ?

Comment: In your Application Server. log4j.xml or log4j.properties, it's the same.